# How To Send Form Data To Two Or More PHP Files?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a Form in an HTML page like below that is sending my data to a page at `http://www.aaaaaa.com/1st-file.php`...

```
<form action="http://www.aaaaaa.com/1st-file.php" method="post" enctype="plain" id="theForm">   
<input type="text" name="NAME" value="Some Data" />
<input type="submit" value="Send Data" />
</form>
```

But I want to send the same data on `http://www.bbbbbb.com/2nd-file.php`. My form is on HTML page and I want to send data via one click on `Send Data` only. So is this possible to send data on both PHP pages using pure JavaScript not JQuery? If yes then how?

### Update:

My both PHP receiving files have codes something like below...

```
<?php
$data_from_site= $_POST['NAME'];
echo $data_from_site;
?>
```

Comment: So you want to use action to go to 1st-file.php and at the same time send data from form to 2nd-file.php, right?

Comment: On different domains? Is any of the two scripts on the same domain as the form?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Yes but if you can tell me any other way then it will be good.

Comment: @user3558931 Yes, both accepting data PHP files are on different domain and sending data Form HTML file is also on different domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an iframe as described [here](http://www.html-form-guide.com/web-form/submit-form-multiple-scripts.html),

```
<input type="submit" value="Send Data" onclick='javascript: return SubmitForm()' />

<iframe name='frame_result1' width='350px' height='100px' frameborder='0'></iframe>
<iframe name='frame_result2' width='350px' height='100px' frameborder='0'></iframe>

function SubmitForm()
{
    document.forms['theForm'].action='http://www.aaaaaa.com/1st-file.php';
    document.forms['theForm'].target='frame_result1';
    document.forms['theForm'].submit();

    document.forms['theForm'].action='http://www.bbbbbb.com/2nd-file.php';
    document.forms['theForm'].target='frame_result2';
    document.forms['theForm'].submit();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imho, if you don't want to use Jquery, the best solution for you is to send an xmlhttprequest via js. see [Request to the Server](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of cURL() and fputs() PHP functions. Here's the sample implementation. http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-submit.html

Comment: As I mentioned already that I have a **HTML** page so no `PHP`... :(